# Why JS Regexp.exec returns an array with more elements than expected?

Tags: javascript, regex, matching, regex-group

I'm attempting to regex match various duration strings (e.g. 1d10h, 30m, 90s, etc.) and have come up with a regex string to split the string into pieces, but it seems that I'm getting two undefined results at the ends that shouldn't be there. I imagine it has to do with the greedy matching via the `?` groupings, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

My code looks like this:

```js
const regex = /^(\d+?[d])?(\d+?[h])?(\d+[m])?(\d+[s])?$/gmi
const results = regex.exec('1d10h')
```

and the results I get look like so:

```
[
  "1d10h",
  "1d",
  "10h",
  undefined,
  undefined,
]
```

I was only expecting the first three results (and in fact, I only really want `1d` and `10h`) but the two remaining `undefined` results keep popping up.

Comment: You have 4 capture groups, and since they're optional, you'll have to filter out the `undefined`s manually afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 groups in the regular expression - each enclosed with braces `(` ... `)` and enumerated naturally - the earlier opening brace appear in the expression the lower order index a group has.

And, of course, the whole match that could be named a "zero" group.

So, result of `regex.exec('1d10h')` contains 5 items:

- `results[0]` - the whole expression match
- `results[i]` - match of each group, `i in {1,2,3,4}`

Since in this case each group is optional (followed by `?`) - it is allowed to have `undefined` in place of any unmatched group.

It is easy to see that if you remove a `?` symbol after an unmatched group, the whole expression will fail to match and hence `regex.exec('1d10h')` will return `null`.

To get rid of undefined elements just filter them out:

```
const result = regex.exec('1d10h').filter(x => x);
```

Comment: you can use the static function `Boolean` for filtering `.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: ah, I see what you mean - it makes sense when I looked at it a bit more, I'll go ahead and mark this as correct, thanks!

Comment: And you could slice off the first element: `regex.exec('1d10h')?.filter(Boolean).slice(1)` - the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` makes it return `undefined` if the regex did not match, but is [not available in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3F.).